# partitioning in MySQL : insert into partition

Tags: mysql

I come from an Apache Hive background.

In that language, you would say the below to insert into date 20220601:

```
insert into table db.tablename partition(date=20220601)
```

In MySQL; I can't get such an insert statement to work. I have been Googling & it seems it just sorts itself out?

So if I did

```
insert into db.tablename
select * from db.othertable
```

Would it automatically partition the ingested data?

I feel like I am missing something here!

Comment: "I feel like I am missing something here!"   I feel like I am missing the reason why you are missing something here.

Comment: "When inserting into a partitioned table, you can control which partitions and subpartitions accept new rows. The PARTITION clause takes **a list of the comma-separated names** of one or more partitions or subpartitions (or both) of the table. If any of the rows to be inserted by a given INSERT statement do not match one of the partitions listed, the INSERT statement fails with the error Found a row not matching the given partition set. For more information and examples" ([docs INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table is partitioned, the values you insert determine which partition the row goes into. Partitioning a table requires you define the mapping, so it's always deterministic which partition a row goes into.

Therefore you don't need to tell INSERT which partition to insert the row into. It's determined automatically by the values you insert in the row.

Partitioning in MySQL is not required for a table. By default, a table is not partitioned. This is normal and sufficient in almost all cases.

Perhaps partitioning in Apache Hive is necessary and does something different from the feature called partitioning in MySQL? I don't know Apache Hive, so I can't answer that.

I suggest you read the MySQL manual chapter about partitioning if you want to learn more about it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html